# If an API request, returns different results for Browser (correct response) and Android (erratic), can the problem be with the API or else ?

Tags: android, rest, api

I'm working with 2 almost identical APIs.

One works fine for both Android and Web.

Other sends the correct response for Web, but error for Android

```
2018-12-11 00:38:11.804 18160-18160/com.gyanpot.wallpaper E/LatestFragment: onPostExecute: <html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("17d322b4d8395b53b95ecc890b849ebd");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://hellowallpaper.epizy.com/wall_panel/api.php?latest&i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

This is the result received in PostExecute.

What can be reason here? The API or my code ?

Answer (score 0):

when looking at that [API](http://hellowallpaper.epizy.com/wall_panel/api.php?latest&i=1) (which you don't even access) ...

a) it is questionable, why you fetch a `HTML` page, instead parsing the `JSON` with [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

b) `HTTPS` is not supported by that server; which leads to issues on Android Pie.

Comment: I make the suggested API request. On web it returns an array of objects.
You can try http://hellowallpaper.epizy.com/wall_panel/api.php?latest